# Good SOP for a prospective MS ECE student

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, computer-science, international-students, electrical-engineering

As an international student vying for a good research university in the US, I have often heard how the SOP is an integral part of any application. unlike the advice for prospective PhD students, there is a dearth of specific resources for Master's students.

In the same vein, I would be very thankful to know, what makes the admissions committee and professors consider certain applications to be promising. Is it the prestige of the college, the research experience or LORs? Does the lack of research papers for a niche field of ECE hamper students' chances?

Answer (score 1):

If the SoP doesn't require you answer specific questions, then it would be the same as for doctoral study. Give your goals for study and thereafter. For a research masters say what area(s) you are interested in pursuing.

If the SoP requires specific questions be addressed, then dow what is asked.

Admissions in US is broad based. Things like GPA, especially in advanced courses, along with good letters of recommendation can make the difference. Institutional reputation means less. Research experience isn't usually essential, though helpful.

Put past accomplishments in the CV. Put future goals in the SoP.